# Get data from AppIntent when parent app is opened from Spotlight in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sirishortcuts, appintents, app-shortcut

I have an AppIntent that is provided as a shortcut and allows the user to open the app from Spotlight in iOS 17. When the shortcut is run, it opens the app with:

```
static let openAppWhenRun: Bool = true
```

I want to perform an action inside the app when it is opened, link the "New Note" action creates a new not in iOS 17.

How can I call the function within the app, or get the data passed by the AppIntent, so that the main app can process this data and perform the action.

I have tried sending a `NotificationCenter` notification from the `perform` function in the App Intent, but this seems very slow once the app has opened.

```
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "performFunctionInApp"), object: nil)
        return .result()
    }
```